# PHP get JSON data from cURL

Tags: php, json, curl

So I have this JSON data

```
{"data":{"id":"1300633073600606211","text":"Can we get mini maps back please?? @CallofDuty"}}
```

and I would like to put the text value of this data into a variable named $tweet_text.
How do I do that?

Comment: See [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: I tried doing it but it returned "Array", nothing more..

Comment: @XwALEwX and what's inside the array?...